# Tradier history API not working for index symbols such as '$DJI'

Tags: tradier

I am using python to retrieve historical price for a symbol. It works perfect when using stock symbols such as 'AAPL'. However it doesn't work for index symbols, such as '$DJI', 'COMP', etc.

is there a reason why it doesn't work for index symbols?

Comment: Obviously, Tradier's API doesn't work the way you're expecting..  It could be that the Tradier API doesn't support these indexes.  It could also be that it does, but it takes a different API call.  Does their documentation suggest that this should work?  Can you test these API calls using your browser?  Does it work any differently there than in your Python code?  Why don't you show us some code?

Comment: Have you requested a list of symbols?  I just looked at the docs, and there's a **/v1/markets/lookup** endpoint for that.  One of the parameters it takes is the **type** of symbols to return, and one options for that parameter is **index**.  I'd suggest making that call and seeing what you get.  Maybe the symbols for indexes are formatted differently than you expect.

Comment: @Steve, I have used lookup checked those symbols and confirms that the symbols I listed above are valid. My python code is distributed in different files and what it is doing is literate the same as a https call (with authentication)
I also checked their document but they didn't mention anything special regarding "index" type
BTW, "lookup" works for both stocks and indexes, in the same manner.

Comment: Ok, well then you've done what I would be doing.  Maybe someone will come along who knows this API specifically.  As I don't, I'm now useless to you ;) . If you don't get help here, do they have Tech Support that you can ask?  Or maybe a targeted community site or something?  Anyway...best of luck figuring this out!

Answer (score 0):

The answer I got from Tradier support:

===========================================

Unfortunately, due to exchange restrictions, we cannot expose this data in the sandbox.
This data is only available to Tradier Brokerage account holder.
Apologies for the inconvenience and thanks for your interest in the Tradier API!

===========================================

looks like they get that done this way on purpose.